# Is there a function can choose data from a specified csv file if there are conflicts while combining two csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files, and I want to combine these two csv files into one csv file. Assume that the two csv files are A.csv and B.csv, I have already known that there are some conflicts in them. For example, there are two columns, ID and name, in A.csv ID "12345" has name "Jack"， in B.csv ID "12345" has name "Tom". So there are conflicts that the same ID has different name. Now I want to keep ID "12345", and I want to choose name from A.csv, and abandon name from B.csv. How could I do that?

Here is some code I have tried, but it can only combine two csv files but connot deal with the conflicts, or more precisely, it cannot choose definite value from A.csv :

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

def merge(csv_list, outputfile):
    for input_file in csv_list:
        f = open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        data = pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=False)
        data.to_csv(outputfile, mode='a', index=False)
    print('Combine Completed')

def distinct(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    datalist = df.drop_duplicates()
    datalist.to_csv('result_new_month01.csv', index = False, header = False)
    print('Distint Completed')

if __name__ = '__main__':
    csv_list = glob.glob('*.csv')
    output_csv_path = 'result.csv'
    print(csv_list)
    merge(csv_list)
    distinct(output_csv_path)
```

P.S. English is not my native language. Please excuse my syntax error.

Comment: If the ID's are unique per file, use them as dictionary keys and the name as the dictionary values. And since you want the values in A.csv to take priority over the values in B.csv, _process B.csv first_ and then do A.csv, so that the final values will be the union of both files and for conflicting IDs will the one's from A.csv. And at the end of it, write the final dictionary out to your final csv file.

Comment: If you show some of your working code/what you have tried, or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then we can help with showing you code to solve the problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @aneroid I understood, but is there anyway to do this by pandas? I have already posted my code, thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, didn't notice the pandas tag earlier. Now that you've added your code, add a small sample of each of the CSVs (5 rows), including an overlap. Are the columns in both CSV's identical? Only ID and Name?

Comment: Are you really trying to merge, or are you trying to [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will put down my comments here as an answer:

The problem with your `merge` function is, you're reading one file and writing it out the same `result.csv` in append mode without doing any check for duplicate names. In order to check for duplicates, they need to be in the same dataframe. From your code, you're combining multiple CSV files, not necessary just `A.csv` and `B.csv`. So when you say *"I want to choose name from A.csv, and abandon name from B.csv"* - it looks like you really mean "keep the first one".

Anyway, fix your `merge()` function to keep reading files into a list of dataframes - with A.csv being first. And then [use @gold_cy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107643/1431750) to concatenate the dataframes keeping only the first occurrence.

**Or** in your `distinct()` function, instead of `datalist = df.drop_duplicates()`, put `datalist = df.drop_duplicates("ID", keep="first").reset_index(drop=True)` - but this can be done after the read-loop instead writing out a CSV full of duplicates, first drop the dupes and then write out to csv.

So here's the change using the first method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

def merge_distinct(csv_list, outputfile):
    all_frames = []  # list of dataframes
    for input_file in csv_list:
        # skip your file-open line and pass those params to pd.read_csv
        data = pd.read_csv(input_file, encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False)
        all_frames.append(data)  # append to list of dataframes
    print('Combine Completed')
    
    final = pd.concat(all_frames).drop_duplicates("ID", keep="first").reset_index(drop=True)
    final.to_csv('result_new_month01.csv', index=False, header=False)
    print('Distint Completed')

if __name__ = '__main__':
    csv_list = sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'))  # sort the list
    output_csv_path = 'result.csv'
    print(csv_list)
    merge_distinct(csv_list, output_csv_path)
```

Notes:

- Instead of doing `f = open(...)` just pass those arguments to [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
- why are you writing out the final csv with `header=False`? That's useful to have.
- [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) doesn't guarantee sorting (depends on filesystem) so I've used `sorted()` above.
- File-system sorting is different from just sorting in `sorted` which is essentially in ASCII/Unicode index order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep one DataFrame value over the other, then [`concatenate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them and keep the first duplicate in the output. This means the preferred values should be in the first argument to the sequence you provide to `concatenate` as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["12345", "4567", "897"], "name": ["Jack", "Tom", "Frank"]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["12345", "333", "897"], "name": ["Tom", "Sam", "Rob"]})

pd.concat([df, df1]).drop_duplicates("ID", keep="first").reset_index(drop=True)

      ID   name
0  12345   Jack
1   4567    Tom
2    897  Frank
3    333    Sam
```